# Add <?php the_content(); ?> to WooCommerce page template

Tags: php, wordpress, function, elementor

I use Elementor page builder on my WordPress site. There is a problem with it - by default it doesn't allow editing WooCoomerce Shop/Products pages. The solution they say is to add  to page templates code. I, being a beginner with no idea of coding, cannot figure out which file to add this code to and where in that file. I have been researching and trying to fix this myself for two weeks now, in vain. Please help me achieve this.

Here's what Elementor say: "[Sorry, the content area was not found in your page. You must call the_content function in the current template, in order for Elementor to work on this page.](https://docs.elementor.com/article/56-content-area-not-found)"

Comment: the_content() is the function which outputs the content you write in the editor (admin area). It seems this function is missing in your template file. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Thanks Andy. I am trying to make Woo Commerce shop/products pages editable using "Elementor Page Builder" plugin in my WordPress site. When I open the pages to edit, it returns a pop-up asking me to add "<?php the_content(); ?>" function to page template code. I don't know where exactly to add this function.

Comment: Normaly you add this function at the place where you wish the content should appear. Just play arround and try some places :)

Comment: Sure Andy. I shall keep trying.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Elementor setting and then check products in post types
2. Go to Products, click Edit on the product you want to edit, input something (ie. a full stop-sign '.') in the WP Editor, click Update. (See attached screenshot.)
   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h06UT.png)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a misconception that `Elementor` can be used to *"edit"* any content.

For `Elementor` to work on a *"Page"* i.e. the post type that uses either the `page.php` or any theme declared page templates it requires `the_content();` function to present in the code.

Issue #1: WooCommerce uses the `woocommerce_content();` function to return the content of the shop.

Issue #2: The Shop output does not use the *"Page"* or Custom Page template - the output is equivalent to the `index.php` or `home.php`, neither of which are editable via `Elementor`.

Unless you are willing to write a pretty sophisticated function to collect all those elements' data and filter them into `the_content();` function, there is currently no way of editing such content directly.

I know it's not the solution you are looking for but that is the current state of affairs. Having said that, some of us are working on all sorts of solutions and maybe, just maybe - we'll come up with a way to have this option available soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

For shop page you should go to Elementor setting and then check products in post types.

Because shop page products are not the content but posts it's the solution.
So inlcude products in post types and edit with elmentor, if for some reason you can't see 'edit with elementor' under shop page, then just open shop page and add

`/?elementor and it would enable elementor`

Answer (score 0):

NO need to add this code in any page follow these instruction.
You just need to clear cache and cookies your browser, Some time website take previous data to show the web page and give this error.
or 
if you open your website private mode then login and go to the page by Elementor you will never face this problem.